# How can I restart a previous stopped task from scratch in Java(FX)?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I have built a button to start and stop some workload of my program, which would need a very long time to finish completely. Starting and stopping my task works more or less. Once the task is cancelled, I am not able to rerun that task by clicking the button again.

After pressign the Cancel button, the buttons text switches back to "Start" (as expected) and when I then again click "Start" the buttons text switches to "Stop", as expected - but the task does **not** start again.

How must I setup that task/button to be able to restart my task with that button?

**UPDATE I Found A Solution**

After reading [this article](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/how-to-use-threads-in-java-create-start-pause-interrupt-and-join), I finally got it working. Basically, what I did is to change my Simulation class to implement `Runnable`, create a `Task` within that class, declared the `Thread` within `Controller.java` and outside of the button-action -> instantiated the `Thread` with button press `if (Thread.isAlive() == false)`.

**SimulationClass.java**

```
public class FullSimulation implements Runnable{

    // Create a Task to run the Thread with
    public static Runnable task = new FullSimulation();

    // This code is run as a Task
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

            // Lots of Calculations....

            // Check if Service is cancelled
            if (Thread.interrupted()) { return; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
// Declare the Thread
Thread simulationThread;
// Press Button
public void startStop(){

    if (simulationThread == null || !simulationThread.isAlive()) {
        // Create new Thread it is not active right now or has not yet been instantiated
        simulationThread = new Thread(new SimulationClass());
        simulationThread.start();
        startStopButton.setText("Stop");
    }
    else {
        // If already instantiated and isAlive() (aka running) then send interrupt signal
        simulationThread.interrupt();
        startStopButton.setText("Start");
    }
}
```

**View.fxml**

```
<Button fx:id="startStopButton" onAction="#startStop" text="Start" />
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello Sedrick, thank you for your comment. I will try to edit it to a minimal working code snippet. But I assume, that it is clear, what my goal is, isn't it? I try to achieve a button, who starts, stops and restarts my task/thread.

Comment: I found a solution by `implementing Runnable` rather than `extending Thread`. :)

Comment: In the future, if you find a solution, don’t alter your question.  Post what you did as an answer to your own question instead.  Without the original text, no one else can see what your issue was, so the question cannot help future readers.